# How to get data form Sub Collection flutter?

Tags: flutter

> How to get all document within sub collection

```
   Firestore.instance
        .collection('AddToCart')
        .document('loginUsersDmYK00vMfyfJgfeKb8x0nnOa3Jn1')
        .collection('Sell').document()
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {

          print(ds['ProductName']);
      // use ds as a snapshot
    });
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 Firestore.instance
        .collection('AddToCart')
        .document('loginUsersDmYK00vMfyfJgfeKb8x0nnOa3Jn1')
        .collection('Sell').getDocuments().then((ds){

          for(int i=0; i<ds.documents.length;i++){
            print("ProductName ==> ${ds.documents[i]['productName']}");
          }
    });
```